# Point Light not working properly inside a glass cylinder?

Tags: texturing, shaders, light, eevee-render-engine, glass

I am working on an antique lamp and want a point light inside it that should work as normal lamp bulbs work, spreading the light all around. However, i have used glass material for the lamp central part and tried the putting point light inside it and now it is not spreading around rather it makes a complete shadow of the glass.I am working in EVEE.

[image: Point Light inside the glass cylinder not spreading like a bulb lamp]

[image: Glass Shader details I used in EVEE]

[image: More Glass S]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the alpha that is controlling the shadow.

Comment: U mean for the point light or is there any for glass material.
I am sorry can u plz be more precise??

Comment: the alpha slider in the shader of the glass material.

Comment: I got it ,its in the shader details Thanks
However it somewhat effects my other shadows like of the whole lamp on the wall which i want to be sharp , so any words on that?

Comment: if you are seeing some kind of noise on the wall that is the artifact of the alpha hashing either increase eevee samples under render tab or set shadow mode to none.

Comment: Thanks Alot Man!
Really Appreciate it.